# Installing SSL certificate on windows server 2008 without removing the old one

Tags: ssl-certificate-renewal

I am a newbie in field of SSL certificates.
My SSL certificate is expiring and i have received a new certificate from my CA.
Currently the option which i have tried out is replacing the old with the new one.
However I want to install the new certificate without removing the old one and later change the https bindings to the newly installed certificate.
I don't have any environment as of now to try this out.
Will it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, importing a new certificate does not affect any existing certificates.